# Adding a progressbar to mp3 AVAudioPlayer playing swift

Tags: swift2, progress-bar, ios9, nstimer, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to set a progressbar and a label to indicate the % of a mp3 file being played. Do I need to set a NSTimer function or can I do it with the AVFoundation?

Comment: This is `AVAudioPlayer` NOT `AVPlayer` you tagged the question improperly

Answer (score 1):

Accomplish what you want using the following information which is available by AVFoundation. Use duration of mp3 file which you can get by creating an `AVAsset` with your mp3 file. And use `AVAudioPlayer.currentTime` to get the current playback position of the currently playing audio file.Periodically check the value of `currentTime` and update the progress bar accordingly. You can use a `while-loop` to constantly check `currentTime` which will make the progress bar appear to increment smoothly. You could also use an NSTimer but depending on your time intervals the progress bar may not appear to increment smoothly but it may appear abrupt.

Alternatively you could use `AVPlayer` or `AVQueuePlayer` instead of `AVAudioPlayer`. With those you will create an `AVPlayerItem` from which you can get the duration of the current song by `AVPlayer.currentItem.duration`.

Comment: Too hard for me (I'm new to swift). Thanks anyway.  The code : `var currentTime = Int(AVAudioPlayer.currentTime)` gives me an error:         \Instance member 'currentTime' cannot be used on type 'AVAudioPlayer'

Comment: Changing that code to `let currentTime = Int(self.reproductor.currentTime)`has worked. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, if need more help let me know or post another question with the `AVAudioPlayer` tag or `AVPlayer` tag, I read those often